# Not getting Selenium Webdriver in Result Window of Nuget Package Manager under References Section in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2012

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise RC Edition from VS Website.

1. I have to work on C# Selenium for that I created a class under File New Project.
2. Under References, choose Manage Nugget Package Option and search for Selenium. No Results are shown
3. Go to Tools<

   Search Selenium under Online Section. Hence I am only showing Single Result with Selenium and that too is not Selenium Webdriver option.

Hence I am not able to install the Selenium and Specflow IDE through this Process.

Please help me with Proper Solution and tell me where I am making mistakes.

[image]

Please see the image link for details.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have NuGet added as one of the package sources. Do this:

Tools > Options > Nuget Package Manager > Package Sources

If https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 is not there then click the plus button and add it as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Does specflow even support VS2017 yet? You might want to verify before you spend a lot of time on this.

Comment: @coding yoshi, I checked and that package is already added man. couple of homework i did. Uninstalled the VS 2017 RC and installed VS 2013 Ultimate Edition.

Comment: The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org'
Now I am getting the above error while installing under Nugget Package Manager in VS Ultimate 2013 Edition.